# how to convert a character to string in swift4?

Tags: swift, xcode, casting

I'm using this code for getting the name of the contact in swift 
this code give me character but I want string

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contacts: [CNContact]) {
    contacts.forEach { (contact) in
        for name in contact.givenName{
            let contactName = name
            nameLabel.text = String (contactName)
            print(contactName)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just one contact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`givenName` is already a string; you don't have to loop through it.

```
 func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contacts: [CNContact]) {
        guard let selectedContact = contacts.first else { return }
        nameLabel.text = selectedContact.givenName
}
```

Comment: He has only one text label.

Comment: Thanks; the asker clarified above that it was one contact.